# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter in microservices

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices

I am following microservices tutorials from the link : https://github.com/sqshq/PiggyMetrics and I was able to successfully start the following services

1. config
2. registry
3. gateway

In each services .yml file, I changed registry to localhost and config to localhost too.

but when I ran the "monitoring" service, I get the below error.

```
ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/messaging/converter/MessageConverter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationRegistrar.registerDefaultDatatypeChannelMessageConverter(IntegrationRegistrar.java:425) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(IntegrationRegistrar.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:358) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:357) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:145) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:328) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.piggymetrics.monitoring.MonitoringApplication.main(MonitoringApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

Error:
[image]

Below error while starting the "auth-service"

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: auth-mongodb
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddress(ServerAddress.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:59) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:114) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.4.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: auth-mongodb
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddress(ServerAddress.java:186) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.4.jar:na]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out this issue. While building the whole source code, I checked the maven debug log closely and found the below error.

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ monitoring ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\pc\Desktop\My_MicroServices\PPP\PiggyMetrics-master\monitoring\target\classes
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\io\projectreactor\ipc\reactor-netty\0.7.8.RELEASE\reactor-netty-0.7.8.RELEASE.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-messaging\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ monitoring ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ monitoring ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\pc\Desktop\My_MicroServices\PPP\PiggyMetrics-master\monitoring\target\test-classes
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\io\projectreactor\ipc\reactor-netty\0.7.8.RELEASE\reactor-netty-0.7.8.RELEASE.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-messaging\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

I deleted `"spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar"` and `"reactor-netty-0.7.8.RELEASE.jar"` from `.m2` and rebuild the project. This time no build compiling error and even able to make the monitoring service up.

Done !

Answer (score 0):

Delete the whole .m2\repository\org\springframework folder and rebuild the again "mvn clean install " . It worked for me .
This happens due to conflicting dependencies for same package .